# Issues while running App developed using Android Material Design

Tags: android, material-design

I have been working on an app using **material design**. I am completely new to this. I have been looking this tutorial for reference [material design](http://www.trueschool.co.in/course_content_show/2-android-material-design-colors-android-tutorial-for-beginners-hd-1080p)  . But I am not getting "settings" option displayed in the top right corner of the toolbar. The toolbar is getting displayed but not the "3 dots settings" button . I am following the same as per the tutorial but I don't know why the settings is not getting displayed. 
Here is my **styles.xml** code:

```
 <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
      <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   </style>

      <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

      </style>
 </resources>
```

and my **styles.xml(v-21)** code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <resources>
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        </style>
```

My **build.gradle** looks like this:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.xxx.yyy.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    }
      buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
     }
   }

   dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
  }
```

I have attached the image of the result I am getting. Please help me get through it!
         [image]

Comment: Share your code for MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem comes from material stuff but the toolbar or option menus. You should share your mainActivity code if possible.

Comment: I just want the settings to get displayed. I didn't start anything in my main activity.

Comment: Settings button is a menu item of optionsMenu. Could you check if method **onCreateOptionsMenu** has overridden in MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

check ur code with it...
menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.toolbar.MainActivity" >
 <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       // toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        //toolbar.setTitle("Title");
       // toolbar.setSubtitle("Subtitle");





    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.toolbar.MainActivity" >

     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="128dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
         android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
         app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay">
     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



</RelativeLayout>
```